# Next.js undici AbortError - how to debug?

Tags: next.js, sanity

I have a Next.js 13.4.13 site fetching data from Sanity.io with `next-sanity`. However, whenever I boot up two things are happening:

1. new updated data from Sanity is not being fetched
2. I'm getting a huge stream of undici AbortError responses in the Console as per:

```
DOMException [AbortError]: This operation was aborted
    at Object.fetch (node:internal/deps/undici/undici:11457:11)
DOMException [AbortError]: This operation was aborted
    at Object.fetch (node:internal/deps/undici/undici:11457:11)
DOMException [AbortError]: This operation was aborted
    at Object.fetch (node:internal/deps/undici/undici:11457:11)
DOMException [AbortError]: This operation was aborted
    at Object.fetch (node:internal/deps/undici/undici:11457:11)
DOMException [AbortError]: This operation was aborted
    at Object.fetch (node:internal/deps/undici/undici:11457:11)
DOMException [AbortError]: This operation was aborted
    at Object.fetch (node:internal/deps/undici/undici:11457:11)
DOMException [AbortError]: This operation was aborted
    at Object.fetch (node:internal/deps/undici/undici:11457:11)
DOMException [AbortError]: This operation was aborted
    at Object.fetch (node:internal/deps/undici/undici:11457:11)
DOMException [AbortError]: This operation was aborted
    at Object.fetch (node:internal/deps/undici/undici:11457:11)
DOMException [AbortError]: This operation was aborted
    at Object.fetch (node:internal/deps/undici/undici:11457:11)
DOMException [AbortError]: This operation was aborted
    at Object.fetch (node:internal/deps/undici/undici:11457:11)
DOMException [AbortError]: This operation was aborted
    at Object.fetch (node:internal/deps/undici/undici:11457:11)
DOMException [AbortError]: This operation was aborted
    at Object.fetch (node:internal/deps/undici/undici:11457:11)
DOMException [AbortError]: This operation was aborted
    at Object.fetch (node:internal/deps/undici/undici:11457:11)
```

These errors give no advice on where/what is causing this error so I'm struggling to identify why it's happening. does anyone have any guidance on what Undici is and what could be triggering this?

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: I removed my previous answer as it wasn't the resolution. For me it seems to have something to do with Next.js cache.

I have 2 server-side fetch functions and both are calling the same method which is querying a Pocketbase database.

```js
    // fetch the CII ratio averages per vessel group
    const ciiGroupData = await fetch(`${process.env.APP_URL}/api/cii/group`, { next: { revalidate: 1 }, headers: { Cookie: `next_secret=${process.env.AUTH_SECRET!}` } });
    const globalGroupCii = await ciiGroupData.json();

    // fetch the CII ratio averages per vessel
    const ciiRatioAvgData = await fetch(`${process.env.APP_URL}/api/cii/ratio-avg`, { next: { revalidate: 1 }, headers: { Cookie: `next_secret=${process.env.AUTH_SECRET!}` } });
    const globalCIIRatioAvg = await ciiRatioAvgData.json();
```

Both are calling the `getCIIforShip` method. Adding `cache: "no-store"` to this Pocketbase method seems to have solved the problem. This method uses the native `fetch` underneath and they just added support to other native `fetch` options.

```js
export async function getCIIforShip(shipId: string) {
    const cii = await pb.collection("cii_reports").getList(1, 500, {
        filter: `ship = "${shipId}"`,
        sort: "data_until_date",
        cache: "no-store",
    });
    return cii;
}
```

I've also had issues with authentication in Pocketbase because of Next.js cache, but again, `cache: "no-store"` did the trick.